# i have the page with a div that load by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

I have a page with a `div` that is loaded by ajax when button a button is clicked. My problem is that if user wants to use F5 and refresh the page, the `div` content became lost!

How can I use refresh for pagses that have load ajax without my loaded content became lost?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `beforeunload`

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){

// your logic here
});
```